# Injecting container to controller with league/route

Tags: php, routes, containers

I'm using league/route and I want to inject my container to controller. Here's what I already have:

Providing RouteCollection:

```
$this->getContainer()->share('route', function () {
    $route = require $this->getContainer()->get('baseDir').'/config/routes.php';

    return $route;
});
```

baseDir/config/routes.php:

```
<?php

use League\Route\Strategy\ParamStrategy;
use League\Container\ReflectionContainer;

$routes = (new \League\Route\RouteCollection)
    ->setStrategy((new ParamStrategy)->setContainer(new ReflectionContainer));
    // The line above is here because ParamStrategy otherwise throws
    // Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'To use the parameter strategy,
    // the container must implement the (::call) method.

$routes->get('/', 'Controller\PostController::index');

return $routes;
```

My front controller:

```
/** @var RouteCollection $route */
$route = $this->getContainer()->get('route');
/** @var ServerRequest $request */
$request = $this->getContainer()->get('request');
/** @var Response $response */
$response = $this->getContainer()->get('response');
/** @var SapiEmitter $emitter */
$emitter = $this->getContainer()->get('emitter');

$response = $route->dispatch($request, $response);

$emitter->emit($response);
```

And I have no idea where should I invoke the `setContainer` method on controller object because it lives only within `$route->dispatch($request, $response);`. What is the proper way to inject that container to my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of points here first of all.

1. Injecting the container in to your controller is Service Location. This is considered an anti pattern (http://ralphschindler.com/2012/10/10/di-dic-service-locator-redux is a good explanation of the distinction between DI and SL).
2. In your examples you are explicitly setting a reflection container on the route collection, this means that it will exclusively attempt to resolve dependencies via reflection and not from any definitions you may have set as that original container is being overwritten.

If you are insistent on using the container within your controller, you can use an inflector on the container to achieve this in each controller. http://container.thephpleague.com/inflectors/ - by using the method in this link you can have your controllers implement the ContainerAwareInterface and whenever the router resolves one of those controllers you can have the container invoke the setContainer method passing in your main container.

Hopefully this helps, I am currently on holiday so can't give code examples but I will edit this answer once I return.

Comment: Thanks for that post about Service Locator. When I was writing this I was tired (night) and I didn't mean to inject the whole container to controller, I just wanted to inject Twig object. Your answer partially helped me, but I had to use `withMethodCall` because with inflector it just wasn't injecting that object or I was doing something wrong. When you'll be home (I don't want you to care about my problem on your holiday :) you can check my code here: https://git.io/vrfvi#L21 Happy holiday!

Comment: Back on Tuesday, will help you out then

Comment: Bumping in case you've forgot that

Comment: I think you forgot about that